# why my compiler give error when i overload increment operator

Tags: c++, oop

I am facing a problem in operator overloading, when I compile my program it gives me an error, following is the code:

```
class box
{
    int length;
    int width;
    int volume;
public:
    box():length(50),width(30)
    {

    }

    box& operator++()
    {
         volume++;
         width++;
         length++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    box b1;

    cout<<++b1;
}
```

The error it gives me is:

> "no match for operator <<"

My question is why does the compiler give me an error although my syntax seems good?

Comment: Why is your question tagged C#?

Comment: If you think it has anything to do with the increment operator, remove it and see what happens.

Comment: hint: writing one operator is not the same as writing all of them.

Comment: You can not print a structure members with cout statement. Write  a print function and call it

Comment: My suggestion: Start with simple operator overloads like binary `+`. Don't jump to flashy `cout`.

Comment: class box
{
 int length;
 int width;
 int volume;
 public:
  box():length(50),width(30)
  {
   
  }
    int &operator+(box &v)
    {
      v.volume=v.width+length;
      
      
    }
     
};
   
    int main()
    {
     box b1,b2;
        cout<<b1+b2<<endl;
        
     
 }

Comment: in the above code i cout "b1+b2" without overloading << operator and it works fine for me why it do not work when i was printing ++b1.

Comment: @jawad You're not overloading `<<` anywhere, but compare the return types of `+` and `++`. (And that's a *very* strange definition of addition.)

Comment: thanks @molbdnilo  your answer clear my confusion a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Return *this from your overloaded operator.
2. If you want to print your object using "cout << ", you need to overload operator <<, otherwise print each member individually.

Comment: class box
{
 int length;
 int width;
 int volume;
 public:
  box():length(50),width(30)
  {
   
  }
    int &operator+(box &v)
    {
      v.volume=v.width+length;
      
      
    }
     
};
   
    int main()
    {
     box b1,b2;
        cout<<b1+b2<<endl;
        
     
 }  please check in this case i do not overload << operator but my code worked fine